# Use sdf database(SQL Server Compact 3.5 database file) without installing Microsoft sql server C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sdf, compact-database

I want to use a database in my C# program but I don't want other users who want to use my program to have to install a big volume software like  Microsoft SQL Server that is more than 2 GB. So, can I use `.sdf` database (SQL Server Compact 3.5) without Microsoft SQL Server?

When I give my published software to anyone with a normal Windows 7 OS (that most probably does not have Microsoft sql server installed) he should be able to use my software without any requirements. My program is really simple, but involves saving data in a database.

I don't want users to be forced to install Microsoft SQL server !

Comment: SQL Server **Compact Edition** can be delivered as a set of DLL's, included in your own setup - no other installation required

Comment: See my blog for tips for private deployement with various data acces technologies (LINQ to SQL, ADO.NET and EF) and platforms

Answer (score -1):

SQLite may also be an option;
http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki

Used it on a project recently and works really well.

Answer (score -1):

Try the site below, I've found it useful in the past. The subjects referenced there are still valid under Visual Studio 2008 / SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5.

http://arcanecode.com/2008/08/12/getting-started-with-sql-server-compact-edition-35/